# DDR3 low power self refresh and Vtt

Tags: ddr3

I'm doing a DDR3 design that should have an emergency "on battery" mode where I send the chips into self refresh and deactivate all other logic. Keeping the address/control bus active (as I'm supposed to) still means that current is sunk into Vtt, can I avoid that if the bus is not wiggling?

My approach would be to tie the supply side of the termination resistors together by active-low/active-high, and disconnect both groups from Vtt separately, then keep the bus in idle state with some pull-up/pull-down to the rails.

Should that work, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you doing hdl or using a pre-existing memory controller in a micro?

Comment: I'm using a CycloneV FPGA with existing memory controller. The FPGA would be powered down in "emergency" mode, which should set the I/O pins to 15 kOhm pull-up.

Comment: I believe the CK pins are both pulled high in an idle state, but the memory controller should handle that AFAIK

Comment: My idea is that I want to switch to battery power if the external supply fails, and keep memory contents for as long as possible -- so I'd like to shut down the FPGA completely if I can. I'd generate commands for the RAM to go into self-refresh, and then I'd like to get the bus into some low-power state. My main concern there is the termination, that consumes about 200 mW during normal operation.